# how do i set the text that my json file is printing to screen i want to hide the text

Tags: jquery, css, json

i have a json data file that stores values and prints it out to the screen but the problem is that the values is attached to a css property width. i dont want the output to be the actual data in the form of a number, i just want to connect the json file and have the value set the width of where the bar must be.

my jquery is:

```
        $(document).ready( function(){
        var MAX_WIDTH = 100; // Define max bar width in Pixels here
        $.getJSON( "js/json/sidekicks.json", function(obj){
            $.each(obj.Sidekicks, function(key, value){
                var color = 'rgb(' + ((value.Score / 100) * 255) + ', #de0001, 10';
                var width = (value.Score / 33) * MAX_WIDTH;
                $('div#' + value.Id).find('span.red_line_fill').text(value.Score).css("background-color", color).width(width);

            });

        });

    });
```

here is a picture to show what i mean. i want to remove the value 20 that prints out to the screen [image]

how would i get who ever is in the lead to display the image "1st"

[image]

Comment: have you tried to remove `.text(value.Score)` ?

Comment: yes i set it to `.text('')` and that worked like a charm (big up @Milind Anantwar ) he helped me debug it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `text('')`(or remove `.text()` to not set any value. But this will not hide already shown text) to set empty value.Try this:

```
  $('div#' + value.Id).find('span.red_line_fill').text('').css("background-color", color).width(width);
```